# Reserve windows 10 app not appearing in notification bar

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I am running Windows 7 and I want the get Windows 10 app thing.

I have tried the `Reservewin10.cmd`, with an error message that says access denied even if I elevated to admin.

I have also tried the `Win10fix_full` file, and I used all 3 methods and waited and it still doesn't work. My computer cant check for updates so I downloaded `B3035583` and `KB2952664` standalone and installed them.

Then I reran both scripts. The `reservewin10` shows the following

[image: Output of reservewin10]

and the `win10fix_full` file still thinks it fixed it but it actually didn't do anything.

I have the 2 prerequisite updates installed, but as @David mentioned below, it may rely on some OTHER updates for it to work.

Error code given by windows update when I try to check for updates is **80072F76**

[image]

Comment: When you say _app thing_ what do you mean? The _upgrade_?

Comment: the little logo that appears in your notification area for reserving win10 @Greenonline

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your Windows is genuine?

Comment: "My computer cant check for updates" You should fix this problem first. It could be that the updates you manually downloaded are dependent on **other** updates you haven't downloaded in order to work properly.

Comment: @Mokubai yes. in system properties it says that it is activated and genuine.

Comment: @DavidPostill that might be the case. I'm going to open a new question

Comment: @RegisteredUser [Troubleshoot problems with installing updates](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-problems-installing-updates#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: @DavidPostill tried it before, doesn't work. Says it fixed stuff, so I ran it again but same error.

Comment: You do understand you don't need this icon to actually upgrade to Windows 10 right?

Comment: @Ramhound this changes everything. Although that's to UPGRADE. Is a reservation required? Do u need to reserve with the icon; is that the only way?

Comment: @Ramhound how do you upgrade w/o the icon

Comment: @RegisteredUser - Download the .ISO when its available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provided a KB article about this issue:

**The "Get Windows 10" app doesn’t appear in Windows 7 or 8.1** 
https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3081048/en-us

1 possible cause is that you run a Volume License or that Windows is not genuine.

Comment: I believe it's genuine.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - You indicated you were 100% certain before.  Why are you not sure now?  How do you not know?

Comment: look which Windows edition do you use. If you use Enterprise you cant get the Icon. If you use Home/Pro/Ultimate run slmgr.vbs /dli to see if it is activated. If the Pro shows MAK/KMS you're out of look. If it says Retail, run this tool: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012 and look if Windows is genuine.

Comment: @Ramhound my bad, i just worded it that way. I'm still 100%certain

Comment: @magicandre1981 It says neither, but it says "OEM_COA_NSLP" channel and that the license status is licensed. the tool gives a validation code of 0. any other info you need from the tool?

Comment: this means you have an OEM version. Which edition? Home Premium?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have KB3035583? You can check in "View installed updates" (and search for KB3035583 in the bar at the top right) or check for it in Windows Updates. I believe it was originally an optional update, but then later changed to an important update (so it gets auto-installed).

If you have it already installed, check your "Customize Notification icons" in your systray (right click on the clock). See if you have "GWX" and if the notification was set to hidden.

Some more info here:
http://www.infoworld.com/article/2907472/operating-systems/windows-10-upgrade-nagware-patch-kb-3035583-now-marked-important-on-some-win7-pcs.html

Comment: Windows doesn't even try to check for updates on my computer so Windows Update is broken, so I downloaded a standalone package with just 3035583 and downloaded it and installed it and yes I do have it.

Comment: gwx is not in the "customize notification icons" menu.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZlozK6l.png

Comment: If your Windows Update is broken, I believe this will be moot because that's how Windows 10 will download (it's going to be pushed). And I believe that's why the notification is also not showing--it needs to be on and maybe you're missing other updates. AFAIK it's not going to be a link you can download, at least until after you've upgraded. From what I heard so far, you should be able to clean install but only after upgrading first (for licensing). Without splitting another topic, what's wrong with your Windows Update?

Comment: whenever I press check for updates, it starts checking for two seconds then stops, gives me an error that says windows update encountered an error. I think I mentioned it in one of my previous questions which has the error code 80072F76

Comment: I'm still testing, but you may not need Windows Update after all. Try upgrading using Microsoft's tool, it will give you an option to upgrade now or create bootable media. You should probably backup first because there is no rollback from Windows 10. I will post again after testing it myself. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I see what you're talking about and I'm making a new question about it.